# Can't detect data source location. Please specify ExecutionLocation in CopyActivity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was trying to use the Azure data factory to copy data from azure sql database to Azure search index. 
I have created the pipeline, dataset and linked services correctly.
I am getting following error message after pipeline/activity execution:

```
Can't detect data source location. Please specify ExecutionLocation in CopyActivity.
```

Input Dataset

```
{
    "name": "Input-notifyDB",
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "topicid",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "createdby",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "linkedServiceName": "Source-notifyDB",
        "typeProperties": {},
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 15
        },
        "external": true,
        "policy": {}
    }
}
```

Output Dataset:

```
{
    "name": "OutputD-notifyDB",
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureSearchIndex",
        "linkedServiceName": "Destination-notifyDB",
        "typeProperties": {
            "indexName": "test"
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 15
        },
        "external": false,
        "policy": {}
    }
}
```

Pipeline:

```
{
    "name": "Copy_notifyDB",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "SqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "select convert(varchar(25), topicid) topicid, createdby from [vMessageDetail]"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSearchIndexSink"
                    },
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": "topicid:id,createdby:sender"
                    },
                    "parallelCopies": 8
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "Input-notifyDB"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "OutputD-notifyDB"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                    "style": "StartOfInterval",
                    "retry": 3,
                    "longRetry": 0,
                    "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "name": "Activity-0-_Custom query_->test"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2017-05-22T10:17:00Z",
        "end": "2017-05-23T18:30:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: My usual trick with this type of problem would be to try and create the pipeline using the [Copy Data wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-copy-wizard).  If I get that to work, it's a matter of comparing the JSON trying to work out what is different.

Comment: @wbob i also use the same trick when adf doesn't work. But it didn't work even after creating pipeline from copy data wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means, in the copy activity within the pipeline, use the executionLocation property within typeProperties (peer of source and sink) to specify the region, like "executionLocation": "East US".  See docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-data-movement-activities#a-nameglobalaglobally-available-data-movement